# Is there a Ruby implementation of HSqlDB?

Tags: ruby, database, csv, hsqldb

Is there such thing?

Actually, it doesnt need to be specifically [HSqlDB](http://hsqldb.org), I just want something similar.

The main feature I need is the capability to [create tables based on DSV text files](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch06.html#N10F46), like you do in HSql with:

```
CREATE TEXT TABLE <tablename> (<column definition> [<constraint definition>]);
SET TABLE <tablename> SOURCE <quoted_filename_and_options> [DESC];
```

Which is super cool for what I do.

Can someone hand me a lib?! :)

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this driver, you can use HSQLDB with Ruby and execute the necessary SQL statements

http://www.infoq.com/news/ruby-driver-hsqldb